# Root logins leave no record of what operations were performed as root - Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook

Tags: permissions, root, users

On page 69 in the book "*Unix and Linux System Administration handbook - Evi Nemeth*" under the section 3.2 Management of the root account -> Root account Login, there is a statement that says "**To begin with, root logins leave no record of what operations were performed as root.**". What does it means to say that "root leaves no record"?

Comment: To be fair, if you are logged into interactive bash shell as root, there may be /root/.bashrc and there is auth log in /var/log when you invoke a command with sudo. But considering that root user can do anything, it can also wipe any log files or history files, which makes it a grand security problem if attacker gains root access ( and by then logs may be the least of your worries anyway )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no log of what commands you ran, what configuration files you edited and so forth *by default*. There's a log entry for authentication, and end of session, but not what root *does*.

This is part of the reason for why many sysadmins prefers `sudo` today; `sudo foobar` leaves a clear log trail that user x ran command `foobar` as root on a given time.

`sudo` also makes it easier to have many administrators on a system, with more fine grained access control than allowed by the single root account.

Note that the above is true for Ubuntu. Debian is somewhat different. RHEL is somewhat more different.